# ViewPath query parameter in SharePoint list causes CSOM to fail Lists.GetById

Tags: sharepoint, csom

It seems due to a recent SharePoint Online update that their lists (when selected using the left navigation) now adds a ViewPath query parameter by default. With this change, it seems like the Provider Hosted App redirect now sends a different ListId and not the Id for the actual list. When I use CSOM to resolve the ListId it results in a "Site Pages" and not the list at all.

```
clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(ListId);
```

This code base did work before the recent SharePoint Online update but now I cannot call my list. If I manually remove the ViewPath query parameter from the list then the redirect shows the correct ListId and CSOM resolves the correct List. The problem is I cannot expect users to manually remove that query parameter.

If I navigate to the list by using the Site Content page and not the left navigation then this query parameter is not present and my application works.

Does anyone have context or direction into how to handle this new change?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on our site. Instead of modifying the list, a script web part on the initial page seems to bleed through. I have ammended the links in the lefthand nav bar in an attempt to circumvent the viewpath query being added. I put in 2 url carriage returns on the end of the link. So far so good for me.